# users next birthday not giving the right value in php

Tags: php

I want to implement Birthday countdown time. Normally, birthday normally takes place once in a year eg within 365 days. I downloaded this code from **stackoverflow** to check the next birthday day of someone who was born on august 22 1982. the days count down should be less than 365 days but the code below is giving a higher value with negative sign.

```
$rem = strtotime('1982-22-08') - time();
$day = floor($rem / 86400);
$hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
$min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
$sec = ($rem % 60);
if($day) echo "$day Days ";
if($hr) echo "$hr Hours ";
if($min) echo "$min Minutes ";
if($sec) echo "$sec Seconds ";
echo "Remaining...";
```

**the next birthday countdown should be less than 365 days**
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have wrong date format in strtotime and return nothing.

Documentation says

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into
>   a Unix timestamp

So if you use

```
strtotime('08/22/18')
```

it will work.

Also you should take actual year if you want say "hey your birthday in this is will be..."

Comment: i have added your solution. it gives this output -19 Days -23 Hours -37 Minutes -19 Seconds Remaining.... I. think the code is counting days up instead of counting down from 365 days. Am supposed to be having something like Eg. your next birthday will be in less than 342 days , 5 hours  and so on.

Comment: yes but you should give date with next year if was in current year. This is your job how solve this logic. Also you can use abs(integer) to plus values. It will be correct.

Comment: Good and Excellent Bro. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this method:

```
$birth_month = 8;
$birth_day = 22;
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('n');
$day = date('j');
if ($birth_month < $month || ($birth_month == $month && $birth_day < $day))
  $year++;  
$target = mktime(0,0,0,$birth_month,$birth_day,$year);
$today = time();
$rem = abs($target - $today);
$days = (int)($rem/86400);
echo "Remaining days till next birthday: $days days!";
```